# Not able to convert timestamp to char or date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I need to convert timestamp value(19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM) to date format('YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') . I'm trying to do it using to_char function (to convert it to varchar and use it in TO_DATE function). I'm getting below error in to_char function. Is this the feasible way or please suggest if anything better works

```sql
select TO_CHAR('19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM','DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SSxFF AM') from dual;
```

```sql
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SSxFF AM'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'  ) from dual;
```

I'm getting below error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: @MT0 , thanks for your edit. This is my first question here

Comment: Maybe you need to put YY instead of YYYY in TO_CHAR('19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SSxFF AM')?

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares There is only a 2-digit year; if you use `YYYY` then it will be matched as `0021` not `2021`. In the [string-to-date conversion rules documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5) you can see that that is not necessary even if a 4-digit year was given. The problem is that `TO_CHAR` expects a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value as the first argument but a string literal is being given and Oracle is implicitly casting the string to a relevant data type using the NLS session parameters.

Comment: And as a side observation - does the term 'Y2k bug' mean anything to you?

Comment: @MT0 OK, thanks for the explanation, I just saw in the first call to TO_CHAR YY was passed for the year, and in the second time inside function TO_DATE YYYY was specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM'` is a string literal; it is not a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Since your string has fractional seconds, you can use `TO_TIMESTAMP` to convert it to a `TIMESTAMP` data type:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( '19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM', 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM' )
         AS timestamp_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | TIMESTAMP_VALUE               |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2021-01-19 21:15:00.000000000 |
> ```

---

If you want the value as a `DATE` data type then you can take the previous output and `CAST` it to a `DATE`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         TO_TIMESTAMP( '19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM', 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM' )
         AS DATE
       ) AS date_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

or, if the fractional seconds are always going to be zero:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( '19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM', 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SS".000000" AM' )
         AS date_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which both output:

> ```
> | DATE_VALUE          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2021-01-19 21:15:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af3669e3fcec5d0375e48c6eb62d7142)*

---

> I need to convert timestamp value to `date`/`varchar` value.

If you want to format the value as `YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS` then you can use `TO_TIMESTAMP` and then `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP( '19-01-21 09:15:00.000000 PM', 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM' ),
         'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS date_string
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | DATE_STRING         |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2021/01/19 21:15:00 |
> ```

*(Note: this outputs a string data type and not a `DATE` data type; if you want a `DATE` data type then use the 2nd or 3rd example.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da7053eb4b5063dbe3ab8f539bc4761a)*

Comment: Sorry If I conveyed it wrongly, I need to convert timestamp value to date/ varchar value.

Comment: @Rachanaa In Oracle, a `DATE` data type always has hour, minute and second components so the latter examples are "dates". It might be better if you [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65793206/edit) your question to tell us what your expected output is so we don't need to guess.

Comment: Using TO_TIMESTAMP function worked for me, thank you :)